# Round function does return different value depending on the type

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, rounding, precision

I just found this strange thing digging for an error in my code:

```
import pandas as pd

dt=pd.DataFrame(columns=['number'])
dt=dt.append({'number': 5.395},ignore_index=True)

r=dt.iloc[[0]]

print(round(r['number'].values[0],2))
print(round(float(r['number'].values[0]),2))
```

So here is the output:

```
5.4
5.39
```

I will solve it easily but should I warn python community ?

thx

Comment: The problem is not in pandas, but in `round()`: `round(np.float64(5.395),2)` -> 5.4; `round(np.float128(5.395),2)` -> 5.39; `round(5.395,2)` -> 5.39. In other words, the standard Python `float` acts as a 128-bit double, but it is supposed to behave as a 64-bit double. I wonder, why.

Comment: @ALollz `np.round` returns an odd result for a 128-bit number: `np.round(np.float128(5.395),2)` -> 5.39.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round The note seems relevant.

Comment: In the first one `round` is delegated to numpy's round which uses a different type of [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer) than Python's own round.